# Packaging multiple Packages, javadoc and external jar dependencies using ANT script in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am making a library. This library has 5 different packages in it.

```
src
|
 ----
    |--- pkg.exceptions
    |--- pkg.a
    |--- pkg.b
    |--- pkg.c
    |--- pkg.main
libs
|
 ----someExternalJar.jar
```

The project setup is as follow
**pkg.main** uses classes from all other packages.
In fact each package uses classes from each other.
I have also written javadoc comments for each class.
One of the class from main uses someExternalJar.jar.

I have looked through different articles but cannot get my head around the ANT build script.

I have tried so far with the following build script...

Compile the source code, generate JavaDocs and package the application in a JAR Archive.

```
<property name="srcDir1" value="src/pkg/exceptions"/>
<property name="srcDir2" value="src/pkg/a"/>
<property name="srcDir3" value="src/pkg/b"/>
<property name="srcDir4" value="src/pkg/c"/>
<property name="srcDir5" value="src/pkg/main"/>
<property name="distDir" value="/dist"/>
<property name="buildDir" value="${distDir}/build" />
<property name="docDir" value="${distDir}/docs" />
<property name="library.dir" value="/lib" />

<path id="external.classpath">
    <pathelement path="${library.dir}/someExternalJar.jar" />
</path>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${buildDir}"/>
    <delete dir="${distDir}"/>        
    <delete dir="${deployDir}"/>  
</target>

<target name="init" depends="clean">
    <tstamp/>
    <mkdir dir="${buildDir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${distDir}"/>        
    <mkdir dir="${deployDir}"/> 
    <mkdir dir="${reportDir}"/> 
</target>   

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${srcDir1}" destdir="${buildDir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${srcDir2}" destdir="${buildDir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${srcDir3}" destdir="${buildDir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${srcDir4}" destdir="${buildDir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${srcDir5}" destdir="${buildDir}" />
</target>

<target name="doc" depends="compile">
    <javadoc packagenames="pkg.exception" sourcepath="." destdir="${docDir}" author="true" version="true" use="true" windowtitle="pkg.exception docs">
        <doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>MyAPI</h1>]]></doctitle>
        <bottom><![CDATA[<i>MyAPI</i>]]></bottom>
    </javadoc>
    <javadoc packagenames="pkg.a" sourcepath="." destdir="${docDir}" author="true" version="true" use="true" windowtitle="pkg.a docs">
        <doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>MyAPI</h1>]]></doctitle>
        <bottom><![CDATA[<i>MyAPI</i>]]></bottom>
    </javadoc>
    <javadoc packagenames="pkg.b" sourcepath="." destdir="${docDir}" author="true" version="true" use="true" windowtitle="pkg.b docs">
        <doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>MyAPI</h1>]]></doctitle>
        <bottom><![CDATA[<i>MyAPI</i>]]></bottom>
    </javadoc>
    <javadoc packagenames="pkg.c" sourcepath="." destdir="${docDir}" author="true" version="true" use="true" windowtitle="pkg.c docs">
        <doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>MyAPI</h1>]]></doctitle>
        <bottom><![CDATA[<i>MyAPI</i>]]></bottom>
    </javadoc>
    <javadoc packagenames="pkg.main" sourcepath="." destdir="${docDir}" author="true" version="true" use="true" windowtitle="pkg.main docs">
        <doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>MyAPI</h1>]]></doctitle>
        <bottom><![CDATA[<i>MyAPI</i>]]></bottom>
    </javadoc>
</target>

<!-- Create Java application archive (Jar) -->
<target name="archive" depends="doc">
    <jar destfile="${distDir}/myapi.jar" basedir="${buildDir}" excludes="**/*Test.class,**/Runner.class" />
</target>
```

but I am getting various errors e.g cannot find symbols from pkg.exceptions, pkg.a etc

Can someone help?

Comment: If `src/pkg/exceptions` uses `src/pkg/a` and vice-versa, it might not be trivial to compile them separately (since both should be built before the other). Can't you merge everything in a single package? Or can you avoid that each package uses classes from each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the reading i did and reply from @gturri i came to conclusion that i am creating a X Y problem for myself so instead of creating seperate packages, i created one main package and created sub folders within that package... so

```
src
|
----
    |--- pkg.exceptions
    |--- pkg.a
    |--- pkg.b
    |--- pkg.c
    |--- pkg.main
libs
|
----someExternalJar.jar
```

became

```
src
|
----
|   |
|   --- pkg.main
|               |
|               ----
|                  |--- folder.exceptions
|                  |--- folder.a
|                  |--- folder.b
|                  |--- folder.c
libs
|
----someExternalJar.jar
```

this way i was able to compile the contents of **pkg.main** and create **javadocs**  using very minor change in the **build.xml**